# how to set to hide initially - javascript

Tags: javascript

I have this code that shows initially how do I change it to be hidden initially?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#hideshow').click(function() {
        var anchor_value = $('#hideshow').text();
        if (anchor_value == 'Hide') {
            $('#hideshow').text('Show');
            $('#message').hide();
        }
        if (anchor_value == 'Show') {
            $('#hideshow').text('Hide');
            $('#message').show();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: You seem to lack very basic understanding of your own code. Inverting a condition is something you should learn _way_ before you touch huge libraries. Look into the `!=` operator or even better the `!==` operator.

Comment: Need minimum understanding of the problem

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to reconsider your code by:

1. first of all, look at the basics of js/jQuery
2. check the visibility of the detail element or use a class instead of check the text of it
3. use the built in jQuery method `toggle` to toggle the visibility
4. to initially hide an element use css a set up accordingly the page

Code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#hideshow').click(function () {
        if ($("#message").is(":visible")) {
            $('#hideshow').text('Show');
        } else $('#hideshow').text('Hide');

        $('#message').toggle();
    })
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/CFExY/